# No target framework found in JetBrains Rider

Tags: linux, xamarin, frameworks, rider

I would like to create Xamarin.Forms project using JetBrains Rider on Linux (Ubuntu 16 LTS).

I know, that Xamarin has no support for Linux, but JetBrains says that it is possible to develop Xamarin app on Linux using Rider.

So after installing dotnet SDK for Linux, I wanted to create Xamarin.Forms project, as you can see on the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fswUD.png) below (Screenshot of Rider), platform I choosed is Multiplatform, type is Xamarin.Forms and shared code is Portable Class Library.

[Screenshot of Rider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fswUD.png)

I get an error "*No target frameworks were found on this machine*" and "*No portable profiles were found on this machine*".

If I choose platform iOS/macOS/tvOS/watchOS, it will create project without problems, I have problem only when creating Android or Multiplatform project.

Comment: "JetBrains says that it is possible to develop Xamarin app on Linux using Rider." I don't think JetBrains would have that kind of a claim. If they do want to support that they have to invest much more efforts than they should.

Answer (score 1):

1.) make sure you have you installed the regular `mono` from HERE: http://www.mono-project.com/download/

2.) download `xamarin-android/xamarin.android-oss_<version>.orig.tar.bz2` from HERE: https://jenkins.mono-project.com/view/Xamarin.Android/job/xamarin-android-linux/lastSuccessfulBuild/Azure/

3.) unpack to, say, `/usr/lib/xamarin.android-oss_<version>/`

4.) Do this:

```
cd /path/to/xamarin.android-oss*/
sudo cp -r bin/Debug/lib/xamarin.android/* /usr/lib/mono
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/mono/xamarin-android/bin/
sudo cp -r bin/Debug/bin/* /usr/lib/mono/xamarin-android/bin/
```

5.) Create a Xamarin project (I used JetBrains Rider)

6.) Add this property-group to your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Unix' ">
    <MonoAndroidBinDirectory>/usr/lib/mono/xamarin-android/bin</MonoAndroidBinDirectory>
    <AndroidSdkDirectory>$(ANDROID_SDK_PATH)</AndroidSdkDirectory>
    <AndroidNdkDirectory>$(ANDROID_NDK_PATH)</AndroidNdkDirectory>

    <TargetFrameworkRootPath>/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/</TargetFrameworkRootPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

7.) Make sure your `ANDROID_SDK_PATH` and `ANDROID_NDK_PATH` environment variables are set correctly.

Worked for me.

REFERENCE: https://github.com/0xFireball/xamarin-android-linux/blob/master/rider-setup.md